# Can i save File object into localstorage?

Tags: html, file, upload, local-storage, filereader

Can i do this?
Like:

```
var zFile = files.target.files[0]

localStorage.setItem("file", JSON.stringify(zFile));

var nFile = JSON.parse(localStorage['file']);
```

After this i can't use file in FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

No, read the file first and then save the contents into local storage.

Comment: I have large files for upload. And i can't save content into 5mb storage.